# Download file from url and then upload to another site via js

Tags: javascript, file, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have a requirement to download a file from a url, then POST it to another site via single js call.

Use case:

1. User enter a file URL then click Re-Upload button

Conditions:

1. The file will be either audio/wav, audio/mp3, or a zip file with multiple wav and mp3
2. I need to POST using multipart/form-data

Questions:

1. How do I create multipart/form-data request via js manually?
2. Correct me if I am wrong, but I think I need to store the file content into an input field once I download it.

   - How to encode this file content into a string that will comes up as byte[] when uploaded?